# O que significa uma expressão entre parênteses seguida de outra entre colchetes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Encontrei este código:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
round(sum(a ** (2, 0.5)[a % 2] for a in nums), 2)
```

Minha dúvida é neste trecho `(2, 0.5)[a % 2]`, qual o nome? Como funciona?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por partes...

`(2, 0.5)` é uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) contendo dois números: o `2` e o `0.5`.

Em uma tupla, podemos acessar seus elementos separadamente, através dos seus índices, sendo que o primeiro índice é zero, o segundo é 1, etc. Exemplo:

```
# tupla contendo dois números
expoentes = (2, 0.5)

# acessando os elementos da tupla pelo índice
print(expoentes[0]) # 2
print(expoentes[1]) # 0.5
```

Mas nada impede que se faça isso:

```
print((2, 0.5)[0]) # 2
print((2, 0.5)[1]) # 0.5
```

Ou seja, eu crio a tupla (sem atribuí-la a uma variável) e já acesso diretamente um de seus índices.

---

No caso do seu código, o índice é `a % 2`: o resto da divisão de `a` por 2. Ao dividir um número por 2, o resto será `0` (quando o número é par) ou `1` (quando o número é ímpar), e este resultado está sendo usado como índice da tupla.

Então `a ** (2, 0.5)[a % 2]` está fazendo `a` elevado ao quadrado ou a `0.5` (que é o mesmo que "a raiz quadrada de `a`"). Quando `a` é par, o resultado de `a % 2` é zero, e portanto ele pega o primeiro elemento da tupla (o `2`). Se `a` for ímpar, `a % 2` é `1`, e portanto ele pega o segundo elemento da tupla (`0.5`).

Por isso a expressão eleva `a` ao quadrado quando `a` é par, e eleva `a` a `0.5` quando `a` é ímpar. Ele faz isso para cada número da lista `nums`, soma os resultados e depois arredonda com 2 casas decimais (a chamada a `round`).

Portanto, é o mesmo que isso:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
expoentes = (2, 0.5)
total = 0
for a in nums:
    indice = a % 2
    total += a ** expoentes[indice]
print(round(total, 2))
```

Mas foi feito em uma linha, "economizando" variáveis e usando uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Excelente explicação.